# Zuul Routing w/o Spring-Cloud

Tags: spring, routes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Is it possible to define/configure `route : endpoint Url` mapping in `Zuul` when spring-cloud / spring boot is not used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for services without spring you can specify the url.

More info: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR6/#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      url: http://example.com/users_service
```

Comment: I'm not using Spring-boot / spring-cloud. Is there a way for a standalone zuul deployment to specify the route/url mapping explicitly?

Comment: You can use vanilla netflix zuul. See https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: @spencergibb I have checked the wiki, but couldn't find the resource that talks about this explicit mapping. Can anyone point me to the correct link?

Comment: The above configuration only works with Spring Cloud, otherwise you are on your own